# Gitlab CI not displaying complete output in terminal

Tags: ansible, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cicd, ansible-lint

I have created a pipeline which performs ansible-lint on $CI_PROJECT_DIR. The problem is the complete output is not shown in UI as compared to running on my local machine.

You can notice the difference in output for both.

Below is the output from my local machine (Ubuntu with ansible-lint installed)

```
**ansible-lint create-dir.yaml -v**
WARNING  Overriding detected file kind 'yaml' with 'playbook' for given positional argument: create-dir.yaml
INFO     Executing syntax check on create-dir.yaml (0.31s)
WARNING  Listing 1 violation(s) that are fatal
syntax-check: 'file' is not a valid attribute for a Play
create-dir.yaml:4:3 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! 'file' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/tmp/create-dir.yaml': line 4, column 3, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: Create a directory if it does not exist
  ^ here
Finished with 1 failure(s), 0 warning(s) on 1 files.
```

Below is output from Gitlab CI :

```
$ find ./ -not  \( -name "*.ansible-lint" -o -name ".gitlab-ci.yml" \) \( -name "*yml" -o -name "*yaml" \)  | xargs ansible-lint -v
WARNING  Overriding detected file kind 'yaml' with 'playbook' for given positional argument: ./ansible/create-dir.yaml
INFO     Executing syntax check on ansible/create-dir.yaml (0.39s)
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
Job succeeded
```

I would like to know why there is difference in output and how to print the complete message on Gitlab CI

Answer (score 1):

Job logs in GitLab CI/CD have a limited length. It's designed for operational reasons, as the jobs can create arbitrary outputs so one could - by mistake or by purpose - output even gigabytes or terabytes of text.

But if you scroll up in the output, you have the abillity to view the full logs by pressing 'Complete Raw'.

[image]